# Minify dynamically generated javascript at runtime for ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, minify

I use a `.cshtml` file to generate a dynamic `.js` file in an ASP.NET MVC controller. So the `.js` file never exists on disk, but only in memory at runtime. It works like this.

The browsers loads a javascript...

```
<script async src='http://example.com/script.js'></script>
```

...that is fetched from and generated by my MVC Controller endpoint:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("script.js")]
public ActionResult GetScript()
{
    // This takes a .cshtml template-file and returns a generated .js file
    return new JavascriptViewResult(viewName, viewModel);
}
```

Is there a way to minify the resulting javascript file that is returned in runtime? I had a look at `System.Web.Optimization.JsMinify` but I'm not sure how I would get that to work. Can I write some kind of `HttpHandler`? Is there maybe a better approach to solve this problem?

Comment: What about [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Comment: @Izzy That's what I'm trying to achieve. But I can' find a way to use that on a dynamically created javascript file. It only exists in memory, not on file. Do you know how to take for example a string containing a javascript, and minify that using Bundling and Minification?

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and after some searching some I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35851403) question. All you need to do is:

```
using Microsoft.Ajax.Utilities;
//...
string minifiedScript = new Minifier().MinifyJavaScript(yourJs);
```

I can't believe it was this simple, yet so hard to find.

P.S. It seems to be part of **Microsoft Ajax Minifier** library, but I don't remember ever installing it manually, so it's either part of MVC or comes with `System.Web.Optimization`.

---

I didn't notice the part about the JS being generated from a view. In that case using bundles might be a solution or rendering the view to a `string` (but I'm unfamiliar with how it's done in **Spark** view engine) before passing it to `Minifier.MinifyJavaScript`.

**Edit:** Another solution (albite somewhat convoluted) would be calling `Minifier.MinifyJavaScript` in the view and cramming the actual JS in a partial view. I don't know about **Spark**, but in **Razor** it's fairly easy to render a view to `string` from another view.